# Not sure how to remove duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm not quite sure how to do this.  I'm adding a screenshot (below) to make it clear. Each row is a specific week of data, with the month being in column A. Sometimes there may be 1 week of data in that month, sometimes there are four. There is a corresponding value in column C that I need to isolate, as I'm needing to copy and paste these values into another sheet, but not necessarily in order. So bottom line, every name will have anywhere from 1-4 values depending on the months they had data. For example, for John Doe in my screen shot, my values would be:

```
6   John Doe    5
8   John Doe    8
9   John Doe    11
```

Currently I"m selecting the block by name, removing duplicates from the month (column A) to get my set of values for that individual. It's time consuming and not helpful.  Is there a way to be able to get excel to recognize that I need the duplicate values removed at the start of each new name?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: have you checked this https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2 ?

Comment: I have already tried the unique value filter and the remove duplicates function. Removing duplicates DOES work, but I can only select one name block at a time. I'm asking if there's a way to select the ENTIRE block of different names (approx 300)  and have excel filter out for each month for each person.  I'm assuming some VBA code may be needed to accomplish this but i'm not sure.

Comment: Select your block before using the remove duplicates function and you should get nice clean unique lines

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing, I can't select the whole list and sort by month because they it will only return 4 results out of 4000

Comment: Don't sort, select columns A through C, use Remove Duplicates, Select All, then OK. It will give as many lines as they are individual A+B+C unique values

Comment: Copy and paste to new columns and then go to Data- Remove Duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**How it works:**

*You need to create Helper column.*

- Write this Formula in Cell `D2` & fill down.

  ```
  =COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$B$2:B2,B2)
  ```
- In Cell `A21` Write `1` as criteria.
- Write this Array Formula in Cell `A22` to get 
  values, finish with `Ctrl_Shift+Enter` then 
  fill Right & Down.

  ```
   {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$C$18, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($A$21, $D$2:$D$18), ROW($A$2:$C$18)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$C$18))+1), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1)),"")}
  ```

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*